# What is the time complexity of the following function in big-O notation?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm working on understanding big O and I have run into a tricky problem.

When I look at this code, I immediately think O(n) just by looking at 
the for loop but the line

```
result = result * k
```

makes me think it is something different.

```
if power(int n, int k)
{
    int result = n
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        result = result * k
    }
}
```

Just looking for some clear explanation on why I may or may not be wrong

Comment: That line has no effect on the control flow

Comment: What language is this? If C or C++, then how can your method `power()` return an `if`? And where is the `return` statement?

Comment: Edited the code *i=1

Comment: Given `int` uses a fixed word length, this means that `result = result * i` runs in constant time. The for-loop is done `n-1` times, since it starts at `1` and ends at `n-1` and each time we increment `i`, so it runs in *O(1)*.

Comment: Your question really boils down to [Does multiplication take unit time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782029/does-multiplication-take-unit-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a tricky problem unless you're using a language like C++ that permits operator overloading and the operator*() method of types of `k` or `result` is overloaded, or else there is a standalone (free) overloaded operator method defined with those types as its arguments. I'm assuming this is not the case, so:

Your loop is of order O(n). Within that loop, what do you do? Do you do another loop? Or call a method that does so? No. Is your system's multiply operator complexity based on the size of its operands? Perhaps technically yes, since a 32-bit multiply will be faster on a 32-bit core than a 64-bit multiply, but that's based on the *types* of the operands, not on the operands' values. Multiply operations are normally of order O(1).

So the overall complexity is O(n*1), or just O(n).

The only way this is anything other than O(n) is if the multiply operator is overloaded, and implemented in a naive way; e.g. if it does the integer multiplication by iterating `k` times and adding `result` to itself `k` times. ***In that case***, the overall complexity would be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

But in any normal case the complexity is just O(n).

Answer (score 0):

This is only a statement,  this is not about group of statements that iterations not dependent on n. So we know about this
 result = result * k 
this is in O (1) in any case its time complexity can't change. time complexity of your code is O (n) not more than O (n)